# Openbravo 3.0 Automation Test Using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jbehave, openbravo

actually I have a task to create automation test on Openbravo 3.0. now my company used Openbravo 3.0 PR15Q4.5. I am finding difficulties since it used smart GWT to create GUI. it have auto generated id for each element. it also used SPA (Single Page Application) so most of element are loaded using javascript and AJAX. Since I only can use absolute Xpath to identify each element, my code is just not reliable and it is so hard to code. sometimes when I run the code I got error "Element not found" or "Element not found in cache". can someone please give me advice how should I do to make better code and fastest way to create automation test???

Comment: try using cssSelector instead of xpath. Also share your piece of code for our understanding.

Comment: Try to open this link [link](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#cube_analytics)

Comment: Openbravo used smartclient to create gui. I need better strategy to make better automation test script. ok noted for using cssSelector

Comment: Hi, I already try to using cssSelector, but, when I try to find css Selector by using fireBug and firePath, it only give me the result like this : **#isc_T0**. I can't depend on ID since it is auto generated id. it will always changed everytime I open the page

Comment: please try to open the link and inspect the element. thank you very much @selva